# Restricting Valgrind to a specific function

Tags: valgrind

I have a big program to run. Using valgrind it takes hours and hours to run. I heard that there is something where we can call valgrind for a specific function in the program. And rest of program will be executed normally(without valgrind env).
Can anybody help me with this. I tried searching it over internet , May be I am missing the term to search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It all depends on what tool you're wanting to use. For callgrind (the profiler in valgrind) there is an option --toggle-collect=function to allow you to collect information inside a particular function and all its children.

However if the tool you're interested in is memcheck (for capturing leaks / memory errors) then there is no available command line option.

Answer (score 0):

Googling "valgrind profile specific function only" and go "I feel lucky"

> In addition to enabling instrumentation, you must also enable event collection for the parts
>   of your program you are interested in. By default, event collection is enabled everywhere.
>   You can limit collection to a specific function by using --toggle-collect=function. This will
>   toggle the collection state on entering and leaving the specified functions. When this option
>   is in effect, the default collection state at program start is "off". Only events happening
>   while running inside of the given function will be collected. Recursive calls of the given
>   function do not trigger any action.

More [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html#opt.toggle-collect)

Comment: That is from the **callgrind** documentation, which is a tool that runs under valgrind.  However I assume the question was about memcheck, which is the most common valgrind tool.  I don't think there is anything like that for memcheck.